# Adding RegEx to Git Secrets

Tags: regex, git, git-secret

I'm attempting to add some RegEx password patterns to git secrets using the --add switch.

`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$^+=!*()@%&]).{6,40}$`
`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[0-9]).{6,40}$`

When I do just a base git secrets --scan command I'm getting `fatal: command line` and I'm also getting `Invalid preceding regular expression` so I am thinking that perhaps I messed up the RegEx.

When I scan a particular file I get the following output:

`grep: repetition-operator operand invalid`

Not sure what I'm missing here. Thanks in Advance!

I expect no errors when running git secrets --scan or git secrets --scan somefile.whateverext

Answer (score 0):

The pattern as a string has to be escaped according
to the rules of the tool that parses the command line.

Some examples:

Double quote C-style  `"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[0-9]).{6,40}$"`

Single quote `'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[0-9]).{6,40}$'`

Double quote raw `r"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[0-9]).{6,40}$"`

Single quote raw  `r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[0-9]).{6,40}$'`

Dot-Net Verbatim  `@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[0-9]).{6,40}$"`